# Sites scores for Procrustes Analysis in R

Tags: r

I am trying to determine the site score coordinates after performing a Procrustes Analysis in R.

```
comp.ord<-procrustes(PA.PCA.hell.trans, PCA.hell.trans, scale=T, symmetric=T, scores="sites")
comp.ord
summary(comp.ord)
```

In the output I get:

```
Number of objects: 235    Number of dimensions: 34 

Procrustes sum of squares:  
0.3938225 
Procrustes root mean squared error: 
0.04093703 
Quantiles of Procrustes errors:
   Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
0.01880827 0.03088994 0.03657154 0.04343953 0.11136274 

Rotation matrix: (##EXTREMELY LONG. WILL SPARE YOU OF THIS)

Translation of Averages: ##Also quite long
Scaling of target:
[1] 0.778574
```

This information is all very valuable, but I am looking for the coordinates that are plotted when you do a graph like: ##I am unsure of how to place graphs in questions.

```
plot(comp.ord)
```

I would like the x,y coordinates of the scaled, rotated ordination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are using "vegan" :

```
 comp.ord$X
 comp.ord$Yrot
 plot(0,0, xlim=range(c(comp.ord$X[,1], comp.ord$Yrot[,1])), ylim=range(c(comp.ord$X[,2], comp.ord$Yrot[,2])), type="n")
 points(comp.ord$X, pch=19, col="red")
 points(comp.ord$Yrot, pch=19, col="blue")
 with(compr.ord, arrows(Yrot[,1], Yrot[,2], X[,1], X[,2]))
```

HTH